# Unable to render image using VueJS

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I  am trying to use VueJS to populate my index.html with photos. I'm using the iTunes API, and the return link is returning a URL to an image.

My problem is, I'm unable to render the photos. `item` is an object.

I've tried to do this. However, it causes the entire web page to not show up (all white). So, that is totally wrong. Originally, v-bind:src= pointed to an image in my folder. But I am trying to dynamically get the URLs.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" style='max-width:200px;margin-right: 30px'>
    <img style='width: 120%; display: inline; ' v-bind:src="{{ item.artworkUrl100 }}">
</div>
```

When I do this, I can actually see the rest of the data on my webpage. However, the image doesn't show up.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" style='max-width:200px;margin-right: 30px'>
     {{ item.artworkUrl100 }}
</div>
```

I am unsure of how to use VueJS syntax to embed images dynamically into my website.

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `{{ }}`

```
<img style='width: 120%; display: inline; ' v-bind:src="item.artworkUrl100">
```